# Wrong usage of std::future?

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, race-condition, future

I have nailed one of my bugs down to this little snippet, and yet I don’t understand why it doesn’t work.

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;

    std::future<int> parseSentence = std::async(std::launch::async, []() { return 3;} );
    ret = parseSentence.get();  

    return ret;
}
```

The code works, but helgrind finds a race condition happening. As the log was a bit long, I put it on a separate file that can be found [here](http://bpaste.net/show/42898/).

Anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the `mythread_wrapper` that is showing up in the data race logs?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I suppose this is pthread’s internal cooking. There is no more code than that. If you want to compile it yourself, don’t forget to add -lpthread (there was somebug recently opened for that).

Comment: You're on a 64-bit platform, such that a 8-byte read or write is atomic.  Does helgrind fire off false positives for correct lockless code?

Comment: @qdii: I see now that `mythread_wrapper` is part of valgrind/helgrind's instrumentation (`hg_intercepts.c`).

Comment: Are you using libstdc++ or libc++?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am using GCC 4.7.1, so I suppose this is `libstdc++`.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393777/current-state-of-drd-and-helgrind-support-for-stdthread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct, so if there's a race condition it's in the implementation of `future` or its companions.