# cannot get Helgrind/DRD work with C++11 thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition, concurrent-programming

I have problems getting Helgrind and DRD working with g++ and C++11 threads.

My setup:
 - RedHad Linux 2.6
 - g++ 4.7.2
 - Valgrind 3.7.0

I tried the program posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393777/current-state-of-drd-and-helgrind-support-for-stdthread), after adding the definitions listed in the first answer, thus:

```
#include <valgrind/helgrind.h>
#define _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_BEFORE(addr) ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(addr)
#define _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(addr) ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_AFTER(addr)
#define _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE -1

#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread t( []() { } );
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I then build the program:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pthread main.cc
```

The program (which doesn't do much) runs correctly:

```
$ ./a.out
```

also with valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==21284== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21284== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21284== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21284== Command: ./a.out
==21284==
==21284==
==21284== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21284==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21284==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 344 bytes allocated
==21284==
==21284== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21284==
==21284== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21284== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

But then, with Helgrind, I get false positives:

```
$ valgrind --tool=helgrind ./a.out                                                  
==21467== Helgrind, a thread error detector                                         
==21467== Copyright (C) 2007-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.           
==21467== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info         
==21467== Command: ./a.out                                                          
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------          
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== Thread #1 is the program's root thread                                    
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------          
==21467== [lines removed]
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== ----------------------------------------------------------------          
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x5B7A058 by thread #1       
==21467== Locks held: none                                                          
==21467== [lines removed]
==21467==                                                                           
==21467== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2
==21467== Locks held: none
==21467==    at 0x4EE0A25: execute_native_thread_routine (shared_ptr_base.h:587)
==21467==    by 0x4C2D3AD: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:219)
==21467==    by 0x55D1850: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==21467==    by 0x58CF90C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21467==
==21467== [lines removed]
==21467==
==21467==
==21467== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21467== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==21467== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==21467== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Similar bogus reports with DRD instead of Helgrind.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html#drd-manual.C++11) in drd manual. It seems you need to recompile the functions execute_native_thread_routine() and std::thread::_M_start_thread(), and link it with your program(And not using the shared library at execution time for these functions).

Actually the macros _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_* are seen by your code but they were not seen by the internal functions of the c++ library code when this library was built. That's why you need to recompile them using the same header inclusion and macro definition you used for your code.

Comment: how exactly to do that?

Comment: Put the functions in a separate cpp file, compile it to an object file and link it to your executable